# I am trying to create a parameter with a drop down function in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2017

The report parameter 'Region' has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter "Region". Forward dependencies are not valid.

This is the error I keep receiving when trying to use this parameter.

I also have a DeliveryDate parameter which it just a standard DateTime type.

I have tried reordering my parameters and also adding a separate dataset in which to run each parameter off of. I'm pretty new to SSRS so any words of advice will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the default value for the region parameter. You are probably using a dataset with the Region parameter in the filter/query. For more help, please provide more examples/queries/design and explain what you are trying to accomplish.